# auth logout doesn't work laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-blade, middleware

I made the files for authentication using the command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I've read on the internet that register, login, as well as logout should work properly, but localhost:8080/logout doesn't work, and I don't know why.

I also read something about modifying AuthController in app, but I do not have that file.

I tried to do it by hand, which means I created a middleware LogoutRedirect:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return redirect(pages.logout);
}
```

In the routes I added

```
use App\Http\Middleware\LogoutRedirect;

Route::get('logout', function()
{
    return view('pages.logout');
})->middleware(LogoutRedirect::class);
```

And logout.blade.php looks like

```
{{ Auth::logout() }}
```

I get the error (when trying to access localhost:8080/logout)

```
Use of undefined constant pages - assumed 'pages'
```

What could I do about it?

---

### EDIT

---

I tried another approach (but with no better results):

1. renamed the route which redirects to '/' to 'home'
2. made a LogoutController in app/http/Controllers/Auth

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use [...]
   class LogoutController extends Controller
   {
       public function logout() {
           Auth::logout();
           return Redirect::route('home');
   }
   }
   ```
3. made the route

   ```
   Route::post('logout', array(
       'as' => 'account-sign-out',
       'uses' => 'Auth\LogoutController@logout'
   ));
   ```

The error I get is

```
  MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:
```

That's the same error I get when I try to use the default logout defined in auth

Comment: return redirect(route('pages.logout') );  perhaps.

Comment: thank you, it worked, i added return redirect(route('home') ); and named the first root (with "/") to 'home'. now it access the blade file, and it redirects to home, but it doesn't sign out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the logout page with GET. But this doesn't work because your logout route is a post route.
Change

```
Route::post('logout', array(
    'as' => 'account-sign-out',
    'uses' => 'Auth\LogoutController@logout'
));
```

by

```
Route::get('logout', [
    'as' => 'account-sign-out',
    'uses' => 'Auth\LogoutController@logout'
]);
```

When you go to the /logout route with the method GET(The default when you go to a page) it should work.

Comment: it worked, thank you so so much!! A little note though, I wrote "LogoutController@logout", but it is in fact "LoginController@logout"